# Why is there a white border around my app icon?

Tags: unity, android, launcher

EDIT:  This is because Unity did not support Android's adaptive icons.  As of Unity 2018, it is supported natively.

- For Unity 2018+, see [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162091).
- For Unity 2017-, see [Jimmy's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/150282/41345).

---

I am developing an Android app in Unity.  I have two versions of the app on my phone, both with identical icons. The white border is only on the newer version of the app. I am using a Google Pixel.

Why is this there, and how do I get rid of it?

Is this tied to my phone or my app? If it is tied to my phone, why is it on one icon, but not the other (they are same icon)? I don't want other users to have this pointless border around the app, as my icon already has a border.

[image]

Comment: I also have a Pixel and have noticed this behavior for many apps on my phone.

Comment: I imagine this is the Adaptive icons issue 
 -
 https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/6w9sab/psa_android_oreos_adaptive_icons_do_not_work_the/?st=j9f0tn32&sh=67820e1b and the fix is to either specify a new icon or downgrade your SDK version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading about the issue at https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-oreo-icon-is-incorrect-on-unity-5-5-0p4.492300/:

- The issue seems to be due to the Adaptive Icons feature in Oreo.
- Unity will be working on a fix in an upcoming major release.
- In the meantime, you can either export to Android Studio and specify an adaptive -icon in your manifest: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html
- or in Unity you can change your target SDK version API level 25 since the features were added in API level 26.

Answer (score 0):

White border are there because of new icon system(Adaptive icons) in android oreo+. If your targetSDK is greater than 25 you have to integrate adaptive icons to avoid white borders. 
[Adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

For integrating adaptive icons in Unity17 I have created small plugin. [Unity Plugin](https://github.com/alokright/UnityAdaptiveIconsSupport)

Comment: I've been meaning to update the answer, but adaptive icons are now supported natively in Unity. No need for a plug-in.

Answer (score -1):

Because there is a white background in your new icon. If you have selected default icon in your player setting then all icon will be saved as it is. See the image below for reference:

[image]

You have to select override icons for every dimensions. See image below:

[image]

I hope it helps you. Good luck.